# In RollingFileReader: file not found

Tags: cloudify

I'm using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I have deployed with success a tomcat service.

In the Cloudify log, I see:

```
WARNING [org.cloudifysource.usm.tail.RollingFileReader] - In RollingFileReader: file not found
```

Can someone help me to understand the meaning of the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloudify RollingFileReader is explained here:
https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify/blob/master/USM/src/main/java/org/cloudifysource/usm/tail/RollingFileReader.java

In this case, it means that Cloudify was expecting a log file to be created, but none was found. This is probably not a critical error.

Note that Cloudify 2 has reached End-of-Life. You should consider moving to Cloudify 3